# Транспонирование матриц - оптимизация кода

Tags: python, python-3.x, матрицы

> Задание:
>
> 1) Реализуйте метод transpose, транспонирующий матрицу и
>   возвращающую результат. Данный метод модифицирует экземпляр класса
>   Matrix.
>
> 2) Реализуйте статический метод transposed, принимающий Matrix и
>   возвращающий транспонированную матрицу. Данный метод НЕ модифицирует экземпляр класса Matrix

Мой код:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class Matrix(object):
    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = deepcopy(matrix)

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str, row)) for row in self.matrix)

    def transpose(self):
        tmatrix = list(zip(*self.matrix))
        self.matrix = tmatrix
        return Matrix(tmatrix)

    @staticmethod
    def transposed(m):
        return '\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str, row)) for row
                         in list(list(x) for x in list(zip(*m.matrix))))
```

2 теста отрабатывают нормально. Тест 1:

```
m = Matrix([[10, 10], [0, 0], [1, 1]])
print(m)
m1 = m.transpose()
print(m)
print(m1)

10  10
0   0
1   1
10  0   1
10  0   1
10  0   1
10  0   1
```

Тест 2:

```
m = Matrix([[10, 10], [0, 0], [1, 1]])
print(m)
print(Matrix.transposed(m))
print(m)

10  10
0   0
1   1
10  0   1
10  0   1
10  10
0   0
1   1
```

А теперь интрига: проверяющая система выдает ошибку по тесту, содержание которого никому неизвестно, в виде Runtime error (задала вопрос на форуме курса - пока тишина). Возможные варианты: код действительно можно оптимизировать чтобы работал быстрее, transposed реализован не статическим методом. 
Как думаете, что можно улучшить?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
class Matrix(object):
    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = deepcopy(matrix)

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str, row)) for row in self.matrix)

    @staticmethod
    def transposed(m):
        return Matrix(list(zip(*m.matrix)))

    def transpose(self):
        self.matrix = list(zip(*self.matrix))
        return self
```

---

[Решение позаимствованное отсюда](https://github.com/Gambrinius/Python_Course), которое наконец удовлетворило "autograder" Курсеры:

```
def transpose(self):
    """
    Transpose matrix, update exist object
    :return: transposed exist matrix object
    """
    self.rows = [list(l) for l in zip(*self.rows)]
    return self

@staticmethod
def transposed(matrix):
    """
    Transpose input matrix object
    :param matrix:
    :return: new transposed matrix object
    """
    matrix = Matrix(matrix.rows).transpose()
    return matrix
```

Comment: ...что-то ничего не изменилось... в любом случае спасибо!)

Comment: на форуме курса мне написали, что была подобная ошибка из-за того, что "косяк был в том, что я в transpose возвращал селф, а надо копию". Сделала вот так:    def transpose(self):
        tmatrix = list(zip(*self.matrix))
        self.matrix = tmatrix
        return Matrix(tmatrix). но опять не прохожу тест .... получается, я не через копию делаю?

Comment: @Lazarevna, конструктор `Matrix(tmatrix)` вернет копию, следовательно ошибка не в этом или не только в этом

Comment: спасибо! ....пошла искать дальше .... ((

Comment: @Lazarevna, можно попробовать ["подсмотреть"](https://www.google.com/search?q=github+"python-osnovy-programmirovaniya"+(week9|+"week+9")) у тех, кто уже прошёл данный курс... ;)

Comment: ...а чтобы и не подсмотреть, конечно я бы уже подсмотрела ))) но там нет ответов в открытом доступе - подгружаешь файл с кодом, как в черную дыру, даже свой подгруженный не выковырнешь, если себе не сохранишь копию ))

Comment: [Это](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Gambrinius/Python_Course/master/week9/matrix.py) разве не то, что вам нужно?

Comment: во я туплю )))) спасибо большущее, что мучаетесь с такими неразумными)

Comment: @Lazarevna, я сейчас посмотрел решения и не нашёл принципиальных различий с моим ответом. Подозреваю что и эти решения "autograder" забракует, но все равно стоит попробовать...

Comment: ....и вот что характерно, не забраковал .... и что же это значит было и кому же теперь можно вообще верить??? (((  спасибо вам преогромное! Без Вас бы я целый курс не сдала - оставалась только одна эта задачка :-)

Comment: @Lazarevna, вас можно поздравить с прохождением курса? :)

Comment: Да! :-) не без Вашей помощи:-) но я еще на 2 записалась, поэтому не прощаюсь ;-)